# Let X = {3^n | n > 0} and Y = {3n | n > 0}. Prove that X ⊆ Y.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I know this should be a simple question to solve but I am stuck.

3^n = 3n

3 * 3n = 3n

How do I write this out further?

Comment: It looks like $X=Y$

Comment: Presumably you made a mistake.

Comment: As @uniquesolution indicates, it appears that $X=Y$ in the title of the question.  However, the body of the question seems to indicate that $X$ and $Y$ are meant to be different.  Can you please clarify this?  Can you also please provide some context for this question?  Where does it come from?  What are you studying? etc.

Comment: What you mean under $3^x=3x$? In real numbers this have $2$ roots. In natural numbers only one $x=1$. Analogue question with second line: it holds only for $n=0$. What you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x \in X \implies x = 3^n = 3\cdot 3^{n-1} = 3m \implies x \in Y \implies X \subseteq Y$

Comment: We are discouraging answers to problem statement questions when no effort is shown

Comment: It is not at all clear to me that the question you have answered is the question which was asked.  In the future, please seek clarification from the question author before making assumptions about what the question is.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. For some reason the formatting was lost when I asked the question. Disappointed how petty this community is.